# CSS with if/then browser logic

Tags: css, cross-browser

For browsers < IE7, I want to use a certain style attribute, while for other browsers I'd like to use another.  Can I do this using a single css file, or do I have to do if then logic to include an ie hack css file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example how you can include an IE6-specific CSS to override specific CSS classes for IE 6 or lower:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/screen.css" title="MySiteStyle" media="screen" />
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/screen-ie6.css" title="MySiteStyle" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Alternatively, you can do it on per-element basis like this:

```
<!--[if (!IE) | (gt IE 6)]>
<div class="header">
<![endif]--> 
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<div class="ie6_header">
<![endif]-->
```

MSDN has some more details about [IE Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) support.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use javascript to detect the browser and apply a class based on that. For example, see:

[JQuery Attributes](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <style>
    /*your style for IE <=6*/
  </style>
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE | (gte IE 7)]>
  <style>
    /*your style for other browsers*/
  </style>
<![endif]>
```

I've found it to be the cleanest solution for this kind of thing.

Comment: Not within "single css file" OP was asking about.

Comment: @ChssPly76: It was an option, not a requirement. But you are right, this option requires *two* files (I normally just override **some** things on the IE specific style sheet). Anyway, I still think this is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Note that this will create the IE-specific style for all versions of IE, not only <IE7

Comment: @Franci Penov: I just wanted to give him a pointer, but you were right, so I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CSS hacks](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks). But you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS Expressions to some extent.

See http://gadgetopia.com/post/2774 for some examples.  These don't get around conditional CSS attributes per se, but they do allow you to dynamically vary the values of CSS attributes.

Answer (score 1):

on the jQuery tip check out this plugin:
http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/

a plugin to do what ghills suggests, this is a nice clean way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The following [page](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/ie7-only-css-hacks/) will show you 6 CSS hacks specifically for IE7. You shouldn't use them, but they're the easiest way for getting the exact right look for your website.

Comment: There **are** easier ways, look at the other answers here.